# Proper way to give a uiview a cornerRadius

Tags: ios, uiview, cornerradius

I have a list like the homescreen of uiviews, they scroll on the pages.

I set the cornerRadius using view.layer.cornerRadius.

This is causing lag when I scroll. The more icons = the mode lag.

How can I properly cut the corners off my uiviews.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you share your some piece of code?

Answer (score 0):

add it to your view

`view.layer.cornerRadius`

`view.cliptobounds = true`

and write the code in `DispatchQueue.main.async {your code here}`